# Table of Customer attributes, customers who buy A, B, and both A+B

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a customer transaction table that looks similar to this:

| Customer ID | Product Purchased |
| --- | --- |
| A | Red |
| B | Blue |
| A | Blue |
| C | Red |
| B | Blue |

It contains all transactions over a long time period
I want to know which customers have bought just red, just blue and both red and blue, so a table like this:

| Customer ID | Product Purchased |
| --- | --- |
| A | Both |
| B | Blue only |
| C | Red only |

I've attempted a CASE WHEN statement, but it ends up duplicating the customer IDs
But when I group by customer ID then I get an error saying the case statement isn't aggregating

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Conditional aggreagation could be used:

```
SELECT CustomerID,
     CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Product) > 1THEN 'Many'
          WHEN COUNT_IF(Product='Red') > 0 THEN 'Red only'
          WHEN COUNT_IF(Product='Blue') > 0 THEN 'Blue only'
     END
FROM tab
GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this worked, though I subbed the COUNT DISTINCT with a >1 since there are more products than just red and blue so:



SELECT CustomerID,
     CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Product) > 1 THEN 'Multiple Products'
          WHEN COUNT_IF(Product='Red') > 0 THEN 'Red only'
          WHEN COUNT_IF(Product='Blue') > 0 THEN 'Blue only'
     END
FROM tab
GROUP BY CustomerID;

Answer (score 1):

So if you have multiple product values Lukasz solution work if you add a filter to exclude the other values, like so:

```
SELECT CustomerID,
     CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Product) = 2 THEN 'Both'
          WHEN COUNT_IF(Product='Red') > 0 THEN 'Red only'
          WHEN COUNT_IF(Product='Blue') > 0 THEN 'Blue only'
     END
FROM tab
WHERE Product in ('Red','Blue')
GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

otherwise a `Orange` would throw off the answer.